How to fix 'The specified @schedule_id does not exist' error in SQL?
I'm trying to add a new schedule to a SQL job. When I create the schedule and click ok, I get the following error:


Create failed for JobSchedule 'tst'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
The specified @schedule_id ('3270') does not exist. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 14262)

I'm unable to add a new schedule to the job even after changing the parameters. How to fix this?

I was able to add a new schedule to the job using the below code.
-- Create a new schedule
EXEC sp_add_schedule
    @schedule_name = N'NewSchedule_Name', 
    @enabled = 1, 
    @freq_type = 4,  -- Daily
    @freq_interval = 1,  -- Every day
    @active_start_time = 090000;  -- 9:00 AM


-- Attach the schedule to an existing job
EXEC sp_attach_schedule
    @job_name = N'Job_Name', 
    @schedule_name = N'NewSchedule_Name';

